# Проблема с запросом бд

Tags: php

> A Database Error Occured
>
> Error number 1064
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order='a:70 ... at line 1.

Как решить? Видать ошибка из за кавычек, но как сделать, чтобы он пропускал ее. Такой запрос:

```
$this->db->query("UPDATE `order` SET name='$name', date='$date', adres='$adres', tel='$tel',metro='$metro',text='$text',order='$ar' WHERE id='$id'");
```

Comment: Для решения подобных проблем большинство используют терморектальный криптоанализ. Воспользуйтесь этим методом стимуляции возле ЦНС, Вы увидите результат через пару минут и он наверняка порадует)

Comment: Очень смешно!
Я приложил скрин ошибки сверху

Comment: SQL-инъекция?

Comment: Нет. Пишу сайт на codeigniter и при внесении даных выскочила эта ошибка, решить не могу, прошу помощи.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$this->db->query("UPDATE `order` SET `name`='".$name."', `date`='".$date."', `adres`='".$adres."', `tel`='".$tel."',`metro`='".$metro."',`text`='".$text."',`order`='".$ar."' WHERE `id`='".$id."'");
```

не ленитесь ставить кавычки!

ps у тебя в таблице order есть поле order? Это правила дурного тона!

Comment: сработало! спасибо

Comment: ставим +1 и принимаем ответ

Comment: @Shrek плюсую) жаль что мое упоминание желательно как писать не помогло XD)

Comment: @Palmervan ну я думаю помогло! и тебе, +1

Answer (score 1):

```
mysql_real_escape_string($ar);
```

или

```
htmlspecialchars($ar);
```

И желательно писать так `name='".$name."'` и т.д.

Comment: не помогло